# Python requests to get Yahoo finance data

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests, yahoo-finance

I'm trying to use this Yahoo Finance API with Python 2.7 and Requests.

Entering in this URL returns the data I need without an issue.

URL - 
http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/BHP.AX/chartdata;type=quote;range=1d/csv

Returns

```
timestamp,close,high,low,open,volume
1443571254,21.8800,21.8900,21.8400,21.8550,773600
1443571319,21.9000,21.9000,21.8400,21.8800,63900
1443571379,21.9200,21.9200,21.8700,21.8800,68800
1443571436,21.9350,21.9500,21.9000,21.9200,16700
```

But, when I try the same with Python eg.

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/BHP.ax/chartdata;type=quote;range=1d/csv')
print r
```

I get a ConnectionError.

I can't understand how the browser could return a result, when Requests times out.

Comment: What is the connectionError about exactly? What error code?

Comment: It was requests.exceptions.ConnectionError('Connection aborted.'

Answer (score 0):

OK, the simple answer is I was using HTTP in python, but the API wanted HTTPS.
Explained in another answer here.

[Python requests.exception.ConnectionError: connection aborted "BadStatusLine"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28557466/python-requests-exception-connectionerror-connection-aborted-badstatusline)