# Python requests times out - requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(10060,

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm having an issue with Python Requests. Running Python 2.7.

This is my code

```
import requests
URL = 'http://www.chiefscientist.gov.au/category/archives/media-releases/'
urlHeaders = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8 GTB7.1 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)", "Referer": "http://example.com"}
r = requests.get(URL, headers=urlHeaders, timeout=None)
```

I'm using timeout=None, so the server can take as long as it likes.

I get this error -

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(10060, ...
```

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28557466/python-requests-exception-connectionerror-connection-aborted-badstatusline), I'm certain.

I have tried http and https, and the server returns 'not found' when I request https. When I use http,  the script takes 10 or more seconds, and then returns the error.

Any thoughts?

Comment: your code is working fine for me. Did you check your DNS settings?

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to do that on Windows (work computer) but I replaced the domain name with the IP address (175.107.139.110), and I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Actually, I tried this on my Linux laptop, and all good. I'll change my Windows DNS settings in future.

Comment: Did you try to use the libraries as Scrapy or Beautiful Soup? Or Do you think that your IP address is blocked in www.chiefscientist.gov.au server?

Comment: It's not an issue with parsing the markup, so I didn't use BS. it works with Linux, so as ozgur pointed out, it's likely the Windows DNS settings I was using