# How to download a file from webpage by python request module?

Tags: python, download, request

I can directly download a file that is around 50 megabytes, but when I use  python request to do so, it does not work. It returns:

```
 r = sss.get(url, stream=True, headers=my_headers)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.8.1-py2.7.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 480, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.8.1-py2.7.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.8.1-py2.7.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.8.1-py2.7.egg/requests/adapters.py", line 426, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))
```

Here is the url that I've used:

What is the problem?

Comment: at a guess where ever is using javascript to download the actual file and not the link that you are clicking

Comment: Updated my answer. Do check it out

Comment: @JoranBeasley, in case after submit the url by python request, it use javascript to download the actual file, then how can I deal with it? Can I still download the data by python request?

Answer (score 0):

Try using *http://* instead of *https://* for your url?

Check out the solution to this question. Might be the solution to the error that you're facing.

[Python requests.exception.ConnectionError: connection aborted "BadStatusLine"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28557466/python-requests-exception-connectionerror-connection-aborted-badstatusline)

Also, it would be helpful to include the url that you're passing into the request in your question.