# Python error: Connection aborted - Network is down

Tags: python, http, gmail, python-requests, gmail-api

I'm using the Gmail API to pull all the emails in a user's inbox. Everything works fine until about an hour, when the request stops returning a response with messages.

I use this code to request message headers:

```
sess = requests.Session()
retries = Retry(total=5, connect=10, backoff_factor=0.1, status_forcelist=[401, 500, 502, 503, 504], raise_on_redirect=True, raise_on_status=True)
sess.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))

try:
            msg = json.loads(sess.get(message_url, params={'format': 'metadata'}, headers=authorization_header).text)
            logger.info('msg', dict(msg=msg))

except requests.HTTPError as e:
            logger.info('error', dict(
                error=e,
                error_code=e.code
            ))

except:
            logger.info('Unknown error')
```

And after an hour I'll get an error like so:

```
[2017-01-08 16:34:17,536: WARNING/PoolWorker-1] 
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=10, read=None, redirect=None)) 
after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', 
OSError(50, 'Network is down'))': 
/gmail/v1/users/<user_id>/messages/<message_id>?format=metadata
```

I thought I might be running into the issue because the access token expires, so I wrote a script to use the refresh token to get a new access token. The process also never catches the HTTPError, but instead prints 'Unknown error', so I don't think HTTPError would be the case.

Do you have any thoughts on how to approach this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your error log says:

```
connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', OSError(50, 'Network is down'))':
```

'Network is down' may have something to do with unstable internet connection.

Another possible cause is your using the wrong URL. In this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28557466/python-requests-exception-connectionerror-connection-aborted-badstatusline), the connection might be for http and not https, vice-versa.

Comment: I'm using the Retry class from the requests library in Python to retry on ConnectionError, so I'm surprised I'm still getting that.

I think I will write my own retry class and then increase the max retry threshold.